# Autocomplete na tecla ENTER em vez de TAB no sublime text

Tags: editor-de-texto, sublime-text-3

Estou utilizando o editor `sublime text 3` e gostaria de saber como faço para deixar o *autocomplete* na tecla ENTER em vez da tecla TAB, pois quando eu começo a digitar uma palavra, o *autocomplete* me dá as opções, e se eu teclar ENTER pula a linha.

**Obs:** estou usando o Linux Debian.

Comment: Você está utilizando o plugin `eminent`?

Comment: @WMomesso Não estou usando nenhum tipo de plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Abra o Keybindings - User e add:

Key bindings é um JSON e está no arquivo .sublime-keymap

http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/key_bindings.html

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["enter"], "command": "commit_completion", "context": [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "keys": ["tab"], "command": "commit_completion", "context": [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible" }
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Allan Kehl, você salvou a minha vida, fazia dias que eu tentava arrumar isso e não conseguia. Abraços.